# Community: This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: discussion, edits

This has been asked before, but not in this context, and I'm perfectly aware of what happened:

While my edit was waiting for approval with already two approvals (**me** being <2000 user) some **other_user** >2000 "fixed" the post editing the same parts of the code block (so it looks for Community being the same and hence a edit conflict), and in consequence Community rejected the edit.

**other_user** forgot to add what I thought was actually important for the edit: fixed grammar, better title and actually asking a question. I don't want to cause any *Meta Effect*, so here is the print screen: [http://imgur.com/a/ZSIhq](https://imgur.com/a/ZSIhq)

> I'd like to come back and
>   re-edit. Just wait for the 2000 mark is an easy answer, **so please
>   imagine I'm with 200 rep?
>
> **What is the best way to deal with this situation?**

Comment: "Wait for the 2000 mark" isn't just the easy answer; it's the right answer. There's not much you can do in situations like that other than leave a comment (not advised) or raise a flag (really not advised, unless there's a major problem). Besides, you're at 2k, now, so the problem is solved as far as you're concerned.

Comment: thanks @EdCottrell, this just happened and I thought to bring it up. It looks like the Community rejection is triggered automatically by editing the code block, so all other edit suggestions are lost. And there is no history to be able to revert the edit...

Comment: If you see that someone else's edit didn't do the edit you wanted, just do another edit. Certainly, if you found these grammatical and other errors before, and can see that the other user did not do them, you can make those same edits again...